# Parse FormData object in nest controller

Tags: json, axios, nestjs, http-post

I have a nest controller which accepts the following DTO, One of the parameters should be a buffer which is read from file
It suppose to read bin file

```
interface LoadFileRequest {
  targetIp: string;
  fileBuffer: Buffer;
  user: User;
}

interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

@Controller('loader')
export class KeyLoaderController {
  @Post('load')
  async load(@Body() body: LoadFileRequest, @Req() request) {
    console.log(body);
    console.log(request);
  }
}
```

My code for testing the controller:

```
import axios from "axios";
import fs from "fs";
import FormData from "form-data";
let headersList = {
  Accept: "*/*",
};

let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("targetIP", "10.10.1.145");
formdata.append(
  "user",
  JSON.stringify({
    username: "user",
    password: "auth",
  })
);
formdata.append("fileBuffer", fs.createReadStream("test.bin"));

let bodyContent = formdata;
const url = "http://localhost:3000/loader/load";
let reqOptions = {
  url,
  method: "POST",
  headers: headersList,
  data: { bodyContent },
};

axios.request(reqOptions).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

At the controller this is the `request body` i get

```
{
  bodyContent: {
    _overheadLength: 380,
    _valueLength: 48,
    _valuesToMeasure: [ [Object] ],
    writable: false,
    readable: true,
    dataSize: 0,
    maxDataSize: 2097152,
    pauseStreams: true,
    _released: false,
    _streams: [
      '----------------------------092840744027446269037569\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="targetIP"\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      '10.10.1.145',
      null,
      '----------------------------092840744027446269037569\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      '{"username":"user","password":"auth"}',
      null,
      '----------------------------092840744027446269037569\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileBuffer"; filename="test.bin"\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      [Object],
      null
    ],
    _currentStream: null,
    _insideLoop: false,
    _pendingNext: false,
    _boundary: '--------------------------092840744027446269037569'
  }
}
```

How can i get the body in the form of object with only the attrbutes of the DTO?
Eventually i got a method which recived the same type of object and i want to call it like this:

```
@Controller('loader')
export class KeyLoaderController {
  @Post('load')
  async load(@Body() body: LoadFileRequest, @Req() request) {
    return await loadFile(body);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I changed the code a bit and now if i send the request from [VS code thunder client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client) it works fine(sort of):

```
@Controller('loader')
export class KeyLoaderController {
  @Post('load')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('fileBuffer'))
  async load(@Body() body, @UploadedFile() file) {
    console.log(body);
    console.log(file);
  }
}
```

When I send this way (The code on the right is the generated code by the extension, Which does not act the same way when I use it):
[image]

This is the body and file I get:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  targetIP: '10.10.1.145',
  user: '{ "username": "user", "password": "0123456789"}'
}
{
  fieldname: 'fileBuffer',
  originalname: 'test.bin',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
  buffer: <Buffer ... ... 119 more bytes>,  size: 169
}
```

But when i take the code i generated in [VS code thunder client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client) (which is at axios request in this post) I still get the body like before (again, as mention in the post)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending a `multipart/form-data` request, you need a form data body parser installed on the server. You can either use the [`FileInterceptor`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) (or one of the derivatives of it), or bind `multer` as a middleware for the entire server. This will allow for the parsing of `multipart/form-data` requests.

---

In your `axios` call, remove the brackets around `bodyContent` so it becomes `data: bodyContent`. You aren't sending an object of form data you are just sending formdata itself

Comment: Look at my edit, I have a problem when the request comes from my code at axiox. If I use VS code thunder client extension it works fine

Comment: @ATT look at the rest of my answer under the solid line